# How to regex match the value of the last appearing specific attribute in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

In a Ruby project I'm working with a badly formed xml file that comes from an external source. I only want one value; the last appearing record node's rate attribute. The xml looks like this (I shortened it for readability)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<diagram>
  <refresh value="30" />
  <margin top="30" bottom="30" left="30" right="30" />
  <rates>
    <rate value="0" />
    <rate value="100" />
    <rate value="200" />
  </rates>
  <data>
    <record rate="121" label="" />
    <record rate="124" label="" />
    <record rate="141" label="" />
    <record rate="141" label="" />
    <record rate="148" label="" />
    <record rate="269" label="6:00" />
    <record rate="701" label="" />
    <record rate="755" label="" />
    <record rate="795" label="" />
    <record rate="850" label="7:00" />
    <record rate="935" label="" />
    <record rate="977" label="" />
  </data>
</diagram>
```

Now all I need is the value of rate in the last record node. I'm not good at regex, but I have been toying around at Rubular and I came up with this expression:

```
<record\b(?:(?=(\s+(?:rate="([^"]*)")|[^\s>]+|\s+))\1)*>
```

Which seemed more or less sufficient; it returns the value, and an extra "/" that I can't get rid of, but if I execute this regex in my code myself I run into trouble; I don't seem to get the same results. I had this code:

```
regex = Regexp.new('<record\b(?:(?=(\s+(?:rate="([^"]*)")|[^\s>]+|\s+))\1)*>')
matchdata = regex.match(s)
puts matchdata[0]
```

I give the entire xml source to this function in the argument "s". But that only returns empty strings. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I know there's parsers for badly formatted HTML, and I suspect there may be parsers for badly formatted XML.

Comment: Nokogiri has various flags to control how strict its parser is. HTML turns off the strictness, XML is very strict. If an XML document fails, Nokogiri lets us see where the errors were by looking at the Nokogiri::XML document's `errors` array. You can still use the DOM at that point, but it might have undergone some fixups to make it valid, so it won't exactly match the original, broken XML. I used Nokogiri for a RSS/RDF/Atom aggregator, and encountered a lot of broken XML, and Nokogiri handled it like a champ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches a single record: `/<record\s+rate="(\d+?)"\s+label="(.*?)"\s+\/>/`. To get only the last one, use:

```
regex = /(?:<record\s+rate="\d+?"\s+label=".*?"\s+\/>[\s\n\r]*)*<record\s+rate="(\d+?)"\s+label="(.*?)"\s+\/>/
s.scan(regex) do |rate, label|
  ...
end
```

If you want only the *rate*, use `(?:<record\s+rate="\d+?".*>[\s\n\r]*)*<record\s+rate="(\d+?)".*>`.

Comment: Great, that worked, thank you! I've been wasting my morning on this:p I see I was also wrong to think the regex had to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, here's how to do it two different ways with a parser using the same XML and String#scan:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

# using XPath
doc.at('//record[last()]')['rate'] # => "977"

# using CSS
doc.css('record').last['rate'] # => "977"

# using a bit of simple Regex
xml.scan(/<record.+$/).last[/rate="(\d+)"/, 1] # => "977"
```

Comment: +1. This is a superior solution. Nokogiri can handle invalid, poorly formed XML without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Personally, I think using an XML parser results in a lot more maintainable code. Even using String#scan, and breaking the problem down into two steps involving small regex is preferable to a single big regex.

Comment: Not going to do this this time because the regex works great and parsing the entire xml probably gives massive overload, but thanks anyway, I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: "parsing the entire xml probably gives massive overload", no not at all. It's very efficient as most of the heavy lifting is done by the system's libXML2 library, which is compiled code and very fast. Only if your XML exceeds available memory could it be a problem but you should use SAX parsing then.